# How to get response header for same key values

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I try to extract data out of a website using *requests*.

I am particularly interested in **response headers** for key `"Set-cookie"`.

However, when I check in *Chrome Developer Tool* there are multiple values for the same key in response header.

I know in requests I just need to issue `response.headers` to get all headers.

How to get all values if I have multiple same keys like `"Set-Cookie"` ?

Comment: I believe all the response values are in the same key, but seperated with a semicolon (or comma).

Comment: Hope this might be helpful. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.COOKIES

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all cookies from a requests response, use `cookies` attribute.

```py
import requests

res = requests.get("http://example.com")

for cookie in res.cookies:
    print(cookie.name, cookie.value)
```